# What is the correct way to close out a scrum sprint in Azure Boards when there are partially completed user stories and tasks?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards, sprint

In Azure Boards, what is the correct way to manage partially done work at the end of a sprint so that metrics, velocity etc, are correctly accounted for? What should you do with the user stories and tasks that were started but not completed within the sprint?

I am finding it difficult to find guidance for sprint planning in Azure Boards that explains what to do with incomplete work items. If you know of guidance that explains this, include links to it.

Comment: I am asking here because this is where Microsoft direct Azure DevOps community queries to from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/devops/) under "Get services advice"

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me if it helped you with this issue

Answer (score 2):

You can check out below blogs about how to deal with partially completed user stories.

[Manage unfinished stories at the end of a Sprint](https://medium.com/swlh/4-steps-to-manage-unfinished-stories-at-the-end-of-a-sprint-3b21edc16d55)

[Incomplete Stories & Tasks in an Agile Sprint](https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/agile/incomplete-stories-tasks-in-an-agile-sprint)

There are mainly two options, move the story forward to the next sprint, or create new story for the spillovers.

You can also check out [this discussion thread](https://www.scrum.org/forum/scrum-forum/25587/how-handle-stories-were-not-completed) and decide which suits you the best.